# RubyTest with SublimeText 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec2, sublimetext

I'm using Sublime Text 2 and installed the RubyTest package. I'm trying to run a test using Command-Shift-R.

I also use rbenv for ruby and have installed gems using Bundler.

The output is:

```
/bin/sh: rspec: command not found
```

The console shows the following command was run:

```
cd '/Users/user/Dropbox/code/app/' && rspec spec/controllers/profile_controller_spec.rb -l 163
```

When I run that command in Terminal, it works fine. Any why it wouldn't work in Sublime?

Comment: Probably a PATH issue...

Comment: I figured as much but that doesn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How are you starting the sublime?

Following url should help you in starting sublime from terminal, which should fix this problem
http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html

Comment: I start Sublime from Terminal already.

Comment: I had already aliased it, but I put it in a different location than the article suggested. I went by their suggestions and it worked great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

To build upon Harun's correct answer:

1. Set up subl for the command line per http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/osx_command_line.html
2. Create a sublime project file per http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/projects.html (this file can be saved in any directory and called whatever you wish
3. Open the project file using `subl --project name_of_your_project_file.sublime-workspace`

Then when you run the tests inside sublime, it will know where to look.

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours struggling with this same problem! I could not get rspec to run within Sublime Text 2, using the Michael Hartl "Ruby on Rails Tutorial." It kept saying

/bin/sh: rspec: command not found

I finally realized that the RubyTest package (https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests) was looking in the WRONG PLACE for my RVM! (Since you use rbenv, I will change my answer for this.)

On my Mac, the path for RubyTest is /Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/Ruby Test

First, to make RubyTest seek the rbenv, I changed the parameter in RubyTest.sublime-settings from

"check_for_rbenv": false, to "check_for_rbenv": true,

Then I dug into the Python code of run_ruby_test.py: https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests/blob/master/run_ruby_test.py

At line 129, inside class BaseRubyTask, it had the wrong path for my rbenv:

rbenv_cmd = os.path.expanduser('~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv')

I changed it to the full correct path: 
rbenv_cmd = os.path.expanduser('/usr/local/rvm/bin/rbenv')

If this is not your path, find the correct path by typing

"which rbenv" and substitute that instead.

After saving run_ruby_test.py, I went to Terminal, cd to my Rails application directory, and ran "spork"

Finally, I opened static_pages_spec.rb in Sublime Text 2. Now all the tests work from it!