# Sublime, Ruby and RSpec (oh my!)

Tags: ruby, rspec, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime and Rspec with Ruby.
I can run code within Sublime by pressing Command-B (Mac).

Does anyone know how to run an Rspec test from within the IDE?

I try Command-B with my spec file, but it gives me this error:

```
./spec_helper.rb:7: uninitialized constant RSpec (NameError)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006249/rubytest-with-sublimetext-2

Answer (score 3):

This works:
http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/04/29/how-to-run-tests-in-sublime-text/

Install Sublime Package Manager

Install RubyTest

Command-Shift-R

Comment: The article seems to be down. Mirror: https://web.archive.org/web/20130902060039/http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/04/29/how-to-run-tests-in-sublime-text/